# ¿Cuándo hay que usar pronombres del objeto indirecto con partes del cuerpo?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, cuerpo-humano

¿Son absolutamente iguales estas dos frases?

- «voy a besarle la mejilla»

vs.

- «voy a besar su mejilla»

O son diferentes? ¿Son correctos gramáticamente las dos?

Comment: I guess "su mejilla" wouldn't be actually *wrong* -- but it doesn't sound right, I can say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las dos frases son correctas, pero el uso del pronombre de complemento indirecto ("voy a besarle la mejilla") es mucho más común. Esto es así para cualquier parte del cuerpo y en casi cualquier contexto:

- Se ha roto la pierna
- Me voy a cortar el pelo

e incluso en sentido figurado:

- Lo que dijiste me abrió los ojos.

La forma con posesivo ("voy a besar su mejilla") solo la he visto muy ocasionalmente en textos literarios o en "manuales de instrucciones" ([Cómo lavar tus manos correctamente](https://www.clikisalud.net/6-pasos-lavar-tus-manos-correctamente/)).